# How to plot only for today?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a new study in tradingview using Pine Script.

```
isCurrentMonth = month(timenow) == month(time)
plot(isCurrentMonth ? close : na)
```

This piece of code could help me display for current month, but I want to **display only for current day**.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution. Hope it could help someone.

```
isToday = false

if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
    isToday := true
```

Comment: You can also use the built-in time() function. Here is the ref: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html